# Facing "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked" to show/hide loader

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

I have a common loader along with `router-outlet` (to load child components) in parent component (AppComponent). In child component, we change value to show and hide the loader before and after calling an API respectively. Hence this error occurs.

for example this is my loader in `app.cpmponent.html`:

```
<p [ngClass]="(overlappingProgress | async) ? 'display-block' : 'display-none'">holaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
```

here `overlappingProgress` is a `observable` type of variable that is resolved through `async` pipe.

In child component, I have a form that needs some data from server. so, inside `ngOnInit` of child component I dispatched some actions(as we are using `ngrx`) in the following sequence -

1. showOverlappingProgress() // it makes loading property true in reducer
2. GetData()
3. hideOverlappingProgress() // it makes loading property false in reducer

so, in `app.component.ts` to detect that change, I listen the changes to update show/hide the loader.

```
this.overlappingProgress = this.store.select(s => s.app.overlappingProgress);
```

I have some idea that it compares the previous/old value with the value of 1st digest cycle, but the value is changing inside the digest cycle so, while it runs second digest cycle, the value mismatch and thus this error occurs.

I mimic this scenario with a simpler version in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdkzwy).

I found some solution that suggested to use `setTimeout()` or `this.cdr.detectChanges()`.

I personally don't feel `setTimeout()` is ok. Besides, trigger `detectchanges` manually may do a lot of extra work as all the child components are suing this loader and every time it will trigger and extra change detection.

So, here I am to get some suggestion on what should be best solution in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has parent child relation. The child component changes the value of parent component that is used inside an expression in parent component.

> To solve the issue, I changed the parent-child structure a bit. I have
> created a new module called `FfLoadingIndicatorComponentModule` and it
> has a component called `FfLoadingIndicatorComponent`. Inside that
> component I subscribed the changes it show hide the loader
> respectively. Finally I import that module in `AppModule` to use the
> newly created loading indicator component from app component.

here the main thing is the separate component and its relation with the app component. lets see the code.
code example:

***ff-loading-indicator.component.ts***

```
@Component({
    selector: 'ff-loading-indicator',
    templateUrl: './ff-loading-indicator.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./ff-loading-indicator.component.scss']
})
export class FfLoadingIndicatorComponent implements OnInit {
    progress$: Observable<boolean>;
    overlappingProgress$: Observable<boolean>;

    constructor(private store: Store<State>) { }
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.progress$ = this.store.select(s => s.app.progress);
        this.overlappingProgress$ = this.store.select(s => s.app.overlappingProgress);
    }
}
```

***ff-loading-indicator.component.html***

```
<div [ngClass]="(progress$ | async) ? 'display-block' : 'display-none'">
    <mat-progress-bar class="ff-z-index-above-toolbar ff-general-loading-indicator" mode="indeterminate" color="accent"></mat-progress-bar>
</div>
```

and finally use this component in `app.component.html`.

***app.component.html***

```
<ff-loading-indicator></ff-loading-indicator>
```

you can find the changes here in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8xd76k).

> Note: `FfLoadingIndicatorComponent` can be imported directly in
> `AppModule`. As I preferred the module approach, I created a separate
> module and import that in `AppModule`